# Extract duplicate points

Tags: qgis, geometry, duplication

I'd like to know how to extract duplicate points (geometrically overlapped) of a point layer, using field calculator of QGIS.
I can extract one or both the duplicates points, is indifferent. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Use [Select by expression](https://docs.qgis.org/3.22/en/docs/user_manual/introduction/general_tools.html#automatic-selection) with this expression: `overlay_equals (@layer)` to select all duplicate points.
2. [Copy and paste](https://docs.qgis.org/3.22/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/editing_geometry_attributes.html#cutting-copying-and-pasting-features) the selected points as a new layer: `Menu Edit > Paste Features As > ... [select an option]`.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a virtual layer where you join the layer to itself based on a distance between two points. Replace `pnt` with your layername

```sql
select a.* from pnt a --Select everything from the point layer once
join pnt b --Join the same layer
on PtDistWithin(a.geometry, b.geometry, 10) --All points within 10 (in the units of you crs)
where a.id<b.id --Where the id is not the same, to not join the same point to itself.
```

Point 1 and 3 are exactly on top of eachother, 5 and 6 ~5 m apart

[image]

Comment: While all of the answers provided so far appear to answer the question, BERA's method has the added ability to identify points within a given threshold distance, not just those points that are *exactly* spatially coincident.  I can imagine a situation where all points within, say 1m, of each other are deemed to be duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

First calculate a field with an unique id (I will call this field **id** for simplicity, use the `$id` expression) then use the [Delete duplicate geometries](https://docs.qgis.org/3.22/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeneral.html#delete-duplicate-geometries) tool and finally use the [Extract by expression](https://docs.qgis.org/3.22/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorselection.html#extract-by-expression) tool in the original layer with this expression.

```
Not aggregate(
    'cleaned_layer_id', -- replace cleaned_layer_id with the name/id of the cleaned layer
    'count',
    "id",
    attributes(@parent)['id'] = "id"
    )
```